# How to compress text files downloaded from the Internet?

Tags: download, traffic

I need to download a lot of large text files. To save traffic, I came up with the idea to automatically compress them between the source server and my computer.

What services are there for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you own the source server you can compress the files stored there and send the compressed files. If you do not own the source server, I don't think there is much you can do.

Comment: I am not the owner of the server :)

Comment: Then I don't think there is much you can do, it's up to the owner of the server to provide compression (it could be that this is already the case but that you don't notice it). If there is an option to download all files in a zip folder I would recommend that.